# Laravel migration DB relations seem to be correct. error message says foreign keys are incompatible

Tags: php, laravel

I bumped into following error.
but my migration settings seem to be correct.
When I was using laravel 6.8. Migration was done successfully.

I am using MySQL and Laravel 7.3.

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'cheeses_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `cheeses` add constraint `cheeses_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))
```

```
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:670

    669|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 670|             throw new QueryException(
    671|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    672|             );
    673|         }
```

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('adress');
            $table->string('adress_detail');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
class CreateCheesesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cheeses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, guys.  I was just wondering. What the difference between BIGINT and UNSIGNED BIGINT?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue probably comes from the fact the `user_id` from your `cheeses` table is a BIGINT while the `id` from your `users` table is an UNSIGNED BIGINT

You should replace `$table->bigInteger('user_id');` with `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and past this up function instead of your up fuction. It will work like a charm!

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cheeses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```